# Can I have two or more web processes using Heroku

Tags: heroku

I'm trying to implement reasonably complex architecture using Heroku. I have a Java application that reads/writes data from one source using REST and puts results onto a queue using RabbitMQ. A Django application then reads from this queue parsing data collected then saves to it's database. The Django application feeds Android and ISO apps through GraphQL. The problem I have is Heroku only seems to let me define one web process in my Procfile where in fact I need two. One for the Java application and one for the Django application. Is there anyway I can make this work?

Comment: Heroku only provides you with a single web address. When you visit `<app-name>.herokuapp.com` you are mapped to `<ipaddress>:<port>`. You do not get a second URL. Either separate your project into two or use a VPS where you can open as many ports as you want.

Comment: Heroku has good reason for not letting you combine codebases. It doesn't scale as well. Long term, the Django app likely will need more dynos than the java side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no un-hacky / good solution to this. And as the comments stated, it is a bad idea to combine codebases here.

Following Heroku's ideas here, you would split these into separate applications/services that communicate to each other via HTTP or the queue.

Many addons you can attach to multiple applications if they are shared. So you have the same queue.

Comment: Thanks! Yes the way to go is to have two apps and share the queue. Here's a link if anyone else comes across this problem. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#sharing-heroku-postgres-between-applications